# JAX-RS cyclic JSON parsing

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I know that there are already some topics discussing this problem, but I haven't find the most suitable solution for me.

To simplify my question, I have two entity, `A` and `B`:

```
public class A{
     @LazyColletion(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
     @ManyToMany(mappedBy="aSet")
     private Set<B> bSet;
}

public class B{
     @LazyColletion(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
     @ManyToMany
     private Set<A> aSet;
}
```

Sometimes I have to send the `A` class with the set of B and sometimes I have to do the reverse. I know that there are the `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations, that prevent the cyclic reference and the `StackOverflowError`, for example:

```
public class A{
     @LazyColletion(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
     @ManyToMany(mappedBy="aSet")
     private Set<B> bSet;
}

public class B{
     @JsonIgnore
     @LazyColletion(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
     @ManyToMany
     private Set<A> aSet;
}
```

This code works ok, when I send the `A` class with the set of `B`, but when I have to do the reverse, the `B` class does not contain the set of `A`, because of the `@JsonIgnore` annotation. Are there any possibilities to solve this issue?

And I have a second question related to this: When I lazily initialize a collection and JAX-RS parsea it to JSON, I got a `LazyInitializationException`. It is ok, but can I set somehow if this is the case, the JSON parser only set `null` to this collection in the JSON object?